# How to know the speed and energy of a particular Digital Design in Quartus-II and DE1-SOC FPGA (Altera)

Tags: fpga, quartus-ii, clock-speed, asic

I did a digital design in Quartus II and my board DE1-SOC FPGA, now I want to read 3 factors: general speed that digital design takes to finish the application, area of the design if it would be a real chip, or at least the area taken in the FPGA, and lastly Power, I wish to have a estimation of the power utilized by my design.

This is to compare with another design made by a schoolmate.

How can I achieve this EASILY by using tools in Quartus.

Power Estimator is available in Quartus 2, but what about SPEED?

PD: As a homework, my design pick up a list of 57.600 8 bits binary numbers (.mif), one by one, pass it through some arithmetic and output 3 sets of 57.600 8 bits binary numbers in ON-Chip RAM. Actually I don't have any proposed constraints, or frequency to achieve, I only expect it to be "standard".

I wish to read any kind of simple estimation of power, area and speed.

Comment: You will have to establish what the latency and throughput are of whatever you have designed, then scale that to the work you're trying to get it to do. What are you trying to get it to do, you don't give any of the pile of detail that needs to accompany your question. You can't do this 'easily' I'm afraid, despite writing it in big letters. The synthesis report will have already given you device logic usage and maximum clock frequency.

Comment: Thanks TonyM, can you explain where to find that "maximun clock  frecuency" in Quartus II? I'm updating my question with more details. I didn't want to extend myself too much on details, because the answer I need is mostly general that can fit any scenarios. I'm just experimenting and learning.

Comment: Good for you and I do understand your approach but you'll get the best help from the crowds if you've provided a detailed question. It shows what the problem is and just how much you've tried to solve it. There are many on here who get off on writing sneering comments to undetailed questions - don't give them fuel :-) Look in the Quartus timing report section.

Comment: Altera (now Intel) has their "PowerPlay Early power estimator" excel spreadsheet for doing the power estimation, you can feed in things like number of CLBs, switching speed, % activity and other things manually or it can take a quartus project file (i forget which) if you need more detailed power stats, although I'd assume that this functionality is built into Quartus (and if it isn't, *then it should be*)

Comment: @TonyM Guys I need to know the computational time of the my design, in Mili Seconds, I cannot find any report like that in Quartus, only something like Fmax, but that's max frecuency, not what I'm looking for,

Comment: Sure but first, have you simulated your design, maybe using ModelSim? As part of that, have you written a testbench for your design? If yes to these, it's straightforward to get the data processing time (something like: number of clocks to do each step x number of steps x clock period). Otherwise you need to do this equation by examining your circuit, which is also straightforward just a different method.

Comment: @TonyM yes I did the simulation on ModelSim, TB and everything, I even loaded it to the board, but afaik Modelsim simulation means nothing compared to the real implementation o hardware. For instance, my board actually takes less than 1 second to get the result while the Modelsim takes several minutes.

Comment: That's good news. Done properly, your simulation should be an excellent/perfect clock-level model of the synthesised circuit - it means everything. In your case, make sure your testbench is pushing through all the data that you want in your application. Then note the simulation run time when your application begins and when it finishes and subtract the two. You can see these on the Wave window or by adding 'assert true report "here" severity note' to the start and end points in your testbench's control process.

Comment: @TonyM I used the waveform, I have a conditional stop instruction in the TB, process start exactly at 0 ps, and get the data at 1ps, when it stop transcript says # ** Note: $stop  ,
#    Time: 181392730 ps, is this Pico-Second?. Also, simulink never asked me the model of my fpga, so I don't understand how can it calculate the "real" computational time occurred in my board.